Replacement pole for clothesline
The 6”x 6”, 10’ long wooden post my clothesline was attached to(8’ above grade) rotted through at ground level after 10 years. I wish to replace it with something that will last longer and won’t require me to remove all the wood that’s still stuck deep to the concrete the post was in.  Would a 2-3” metal pole, hold the weight of a 25’ long “loaded” clothesline?

I would add one or two guy wire/cable to a three inch pole.  A loaded clothesline plus some wind is a lot of force.  I imagine the 6x6 was just plain/common wood, not pressure treated or cedar type(rot resistant).

Thank you.  The post was cedar.  West coast weather did the damage.

Yes, my sister still uses the metal poles about 2" diameter put in by my grandfather over 70 years ago.
However, I think they will be on my list of jobs daily soon...

Are they thick wall or solid poles?

@crip659 thick wall with welded on caps and little cross bars 6" down from the top to make fixing the line easy.
